# Android install apk with Intent.VIEW_ACTION not working with File provider

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fileprovider, android-7.0-nougat, viewaction

My app has an auto-update feature that download an APK and when the download is finished that a Intent.VIEW_ACTION to open the app and let the user install the downloaded apk

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("file://" + destination);
Intent install = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
install.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
install.setDataAndType(uri,
    manager.getMimeTypeForDownloadedFile(downloadId));
activity.startActivity(install);
```

This works great for all the device < 24

Now with Android 24 apparently we are not allowed any more to start intents with file:/// and after some googling it was advised to use A File Provider

new code:

```
Intent install = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
install.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
install.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
Uri apkUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(AutoUpdate.this,
    BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", file);
install.setDataAndType(apkUri,
    manager.getMimeTypeForDownloadedFile(downloadId));
activity.startActivity(install);
```

Now activity.startActivity(install); throws an error

> No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW
> dat=content://com.xxxx.xx.provider/MyFolder/Download/MyApkFile.apk
> typ=application/vnd.android.package-archive flg=0x4000000 }

Is there any way I can open the APK viewer in Android 7 (24) ?

Comment: Use `ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE`. That [worked for me](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=205827) as of the June edition of the N Developer Preview.

Comment: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.INSTALL_PACKAGE ...

Comment: I have no problems with `ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE`, using a `FileProvider` to serve the APK, when tested on a Nexus 9 running Android 7.0 (build NRD90M). Compared with your `Intent`, besides the action string difference, I do not use `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`, and I use `setData()` rather than `setDataAndType()`.

Comment: where do you get "file" from? the last argument in `getUriForFile`

Comment: Intent.ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE is deprecated, use Intent.ACTION_VIEW

Comment: It this behavior still allowed in apps with `API 31` and above?  Wouldn't this behavior be flagged by Play Protect as a Dynamic Downloader.

Answer (score 192, accepted):

After a lot of trying I have been able to solve this by creating different Intents for anything lower than Nougat as using the FileProvider to create an install intent with Android Versions before Nougat causes the error:

```
ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.INSTALL_PACKAGE dat=content://XXX.apk flg=0x1 }
```

While using a normal Uri on Android Nougat creates the following error:

```
FileUriExposedException: file:///XXX.apk exposed beyond app through Intent.getData()
```

My solution which is working for me with Android N on the emulator and a phone running Android M.

```
File toInstall = new File(appDirectory, appName + ".apk");
Intent intent;
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
    Uri apkUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(activity, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".fileprovider", toInstall);
    intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE);
    intent.setData(apkUri);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
} else {
    Uri apkUri = Uri.fromFile(toInstall);
    intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setDataAndType(apkUri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
}
activity.startActivity(intent);
```

**UPDATE FOR Android Nougat 7.1:**

You also need to add the permission REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES in your manifest. Its available from Api Level 23 (Android 6.0 Marshmallow) and required from Level 25 (Android 7.1 Nougat).

**UPDATE:**

Remember to request the permissions for read and write to external storage if the file you try to install is on the external storage. And also to set up a correct FileProvider for Android Nougat and above.

First check if you have write permission by calling `canReadWriteExternal()` below, if not call `requestPermission()` before:

```
private static final int REQUEST_WRITE_PERMISSION = 786;

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_WRITE_PERMISSION && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        Toast.makeText(this, "Permission granted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

private void requestPermission() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
        requestPermissions(new String[]{ Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_WRITE_PERMISSION);
}

private boolean canReadWriteExternal() {
    return Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M ||
            ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
}
```

Here is an example of a file provider for the Download folder on the external storage. **AndroidManifest.xml**:

```
<application ... >
    ...

    <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/filepaths" />
    </provider>
</application>
```

**resources/xml/filepaths.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="external_download" path="Download"/>
</paths>
```

If you get an error while installing the .apk saying something like "There is a problem parsing the package." it could be that you haven't asked for the read/write permission or the file you try to install doesn't exist or is corrupt.

**UPDATE FOR Android Oreo 8.0:**

You have to check if current application is allowed to install the APK on Android Oreo 8.0 or above.

You can check if your app is allowed to install APK by using [canRequestPackageInstalls](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager#canRequestPackageInstalls()) method of PackageManager class. If it returns false, then you can launch intent with [ACTION_MANAGE_UNKNOWN_APP_SOURCES](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings#ACTION_MANAGE_UNKNOWN_APP_SOURCES) action to launch settings dialog where user can allow the app to install APKs.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O 
        && !getPackageManager().canRequestPackageInstalls()) {
    Intent unknownAppSourceIntent = new Intent()
            .setAction(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_UNKNOWN_APP_SOURCES)
            .setData(Uri.parse(String.format("package:%s", getPackageName())));

    unknownAppSourceDialog.launch(unknownAppSourceIntent);
} else {
    // App already have the permission to install so launch the APK installation.
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Make sure you add the following code to your activity to receive the result of intent.

```
ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> unknownAppSourceDialog = registerForActivityResult(
    new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
    result -> {
        if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            // User has allowed app to install APKs
            // so we can now launch APK installation.
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Comment: can you post where you get `toInstall`?

Comment: @emaillenin I have added it. It just a File pointing to the .apk you want to install.

Comment: My issue was that I was calling `setFlags` twice which basically resets the first flag. I had to use `addFlag` instead.

Comment: but its not opening app after installing

Comment: @andro if the user down't press open after install the app wont open. Then you need to create a new intent to open that app.

Comment: @just_user after installing done its not asking open . it just closing it

Comment: @just_user can you look into my code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41762043/android-n-install-apk-viva-code?noredirect=1#comment70715648_41762043

Comment: @just_user i am trying to do the same via shell using pm install -r its throwing security exception in N whereas it works in M. Have you came across it ?

Comment: I did that, but I'm getting an error saying "There is a problem parsing the package". If I use a public directory, the error is gone, but unfortunately I need to use a private one.

Comment: Then you should probably look into FileProvider https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html. But you have to share the file publicly for the package manger to be able to read it. So if you have it downloaded privately, copy it to a public location and delete after install is done.

Comment: Great answer - thank you! It's worth mentioning that as of **Oreo** you must also add the **REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES** permission to your manifest. Otherwise it just silently fails.

Comment: Under Nougat this isn't working for me. 
 I get an exception android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.INSTALL_PACKAGE dat=content://com.myApp.provider/external_files/myMyAppAPK/CheckIn20180122.APK flg=0x1 }

Comment: OK this is bizarre - in my case I followed this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40098073/no-activity-found-to-handle-intent-act-android-intent-action-view-trying-to-in

And that fixed it.  Basically because I had renamed the APK it didn't work.  Renamed it back to the APK's original name and it worked!

Comment: @ChrisNevill that is bizarre!

Comment: @just_user :- I have just followed your instruction but I am getting issue classNotFoundException . can you please let me know why i am getting this one.

Comment: @just_user `Process: xxxx, PID: 4224
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application xxxx.MyApplication: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "xxxx.MyApplication" on path: DexPathList[[],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/xxxx-1/lib/arm, /data/app/xxxx-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:587)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4932)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(ActivityThread.java)`                        **Issue that I am getting**

Comment: @Peter that looks like a different issue. But does that activity with that package name exist and is it in your Manifest?

Comment: @just_user yes          **Mainly I am creating the apk by using splits**

Comment: In Android Oreo you need: if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O && (!getPackageManager().canRequestPackageInstalls()) ) {
                                startActivityForResult(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_UNKNOWN_APP_SOURCES).setData(Uri.parse(String.format("package:%s", getPackageName()))), 1234);
                            }

Comment: For Oreo I need to use setDataAndType too instead of setData, else it throws the ActivityNotFoundException @CrisNevill mentioned

Comment: Make a note `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" />` is required for Android N(Nougot)

Comment: @AkashAmin Right you are, from Nougat 7.1 more specifically. I have updated the post with it.

Comment: Where it is the `activity` defines ?

Comment: @Spritzig if you are calling the code above from an activity already you don't need **activity.** in front of startActivity(). Otherwise just pass the activity you are calling this from! It's not important where it's declared and its very basic android knowledge.

Comment: i'm still getting `ActivityNotFoundException` on android api 27

Comment: @just_user I think you mean to say  `== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED` instead in `canReadWriteExternal` function

Comment: this methods not work on samsung A12 model with android 11. package installer gives error "there was a problem parsing the package"

Comment: Have you tried to google that? Because that issue is probably not related to the code above. @gturedi

Comment: i fixed issue saving apk to app internal storage. samsung devices giving error if you try to install apk from public external folder like "Download". @just_user

Comment: also this way i get rid of requesting write file permission

Comment: To be clear, some say `REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES` requires since Android 7 Nougat(API 24). It's not true. the permission requires Android 8 Oreo(API 26) or above.

Answer (score 18):

I had this problem when calling start activity.after pausing my current activity, it suddenly came back and called onResume. like nothing happened. my problem was with this permission in manifest:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" />
```

almost no one mentioned that. so remember this.
in sdk >= 24 you need to use provider because it needs an intent starting with file:///
below sdk 24 you should give uri starting with content:///
so that's why we need file provider for sdk 24 and above. I don't think I need to write any codes for this as @just_user has written correct answer.
https://stacklearn.ir

Comment: I believe your comment is reversed.  For SDK >= 24 the URI needs to begin with 'content:///'.  below SDK 24 it should begin with 'file:///'

Comment: worked in android 13. thanks. upvoted.

Answer (score 6):

This could be the problem, you have

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
```

in your example it should be

```
install.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
```

as install is the name of the intent.

Comment: Did anything worked out for you? I am not able to share my file uri with email application.

Comment: I've been switching over from using file:/// to content:// and was having trouble opening the files from the file provider for a while now. This fixed my issue.

Answer (score 2):

You should note that for API < 24 you need to use:

```
        setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(apkFile), "application/vnd.android.package-archive")
```

instead of setting data and type separately:

```
data = Uri.fromFile(apkFile)
    type = "application/vnd.android.package-archive"
```

otherwise, you will get ActivityNotFoundException

Comment: Just always use `DataAndType` then there is no problem.

Answer (score 0):

For all of those who face the issue "There was a problem parsing this package.".

Set manualy the premissions.

```
ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
```

See this exemple :
[Download And Install App Programmatically](http://www.wepstech.com/download-and-install-app-programmatically/#)