# intent to install apk on android N

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I'm trying to Intent to install APK on android N.
I use the following code:

```
File toInstall = new File(appDirectory, appName + ".apk");
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
    Uri apkUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(activity, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", toInstall);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE);
    intent.setData(apkUri);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    activity.startActivity(intent)
} else {
    Uri apkUri = Uri.fromFile(toInstall);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setDataAndType(apkUri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    activity.startActivity(intent);
}
```

but I face the following error:

```
    FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-5
Process: com.myapp.myapp, PID: 16557
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.XmlResourceParser android.content.pm.ProviderInfo.loadXmlMetaData(android.content.pm.PackageManager, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.parsePathStrategy(FileProvider.java:583)
at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.getPathStrategy(FileProvider.java:557)
at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:399)
at ir.myapp.picwriter.service.MyService$1.run(MyService.java:57)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

Which the error is in this line:

```
Uri apkUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(activity, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", toInstall);
```

Comment: IIRC, that error means that Android cannot find your `FileProvider` in the manifest with your specified authority string.

Comment: @CommonsWare so what should I do?

Comment: Since I cannot see your manifest, or your `FileProvider` metadata XML resource, I cannot really give you more advice. If you edit your question and add those to it, perhaps we can point out what to change.

Comment: @CommonsWare I have no `FileProvider` or any `FileProvider` in my manifest I just copied the code from https://stackoverflow.com/a/40131196/7297151 and searched for error but I couldn't reach any answer so I asked a question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had many problems with it finally I found the answer. here is the answer hope its useful for you.

```
    File toInstall = new File(url);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        File newFile = new File(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "apps"), getImageNameByUrl(appUrl));
        Uri apkUri = getUriForFile(context, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID+".provider", newFile);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE);
        intent.setData(apkUri);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    } else {
        Uri apkUri = Uri.fromFile(toInstall);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(apkUri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
```

`manifest`:

```
    <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
    </provider>
```

and `file_paths`:

```
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="." path="." />
</paths>
```

and permission for API>25

```
<uses-permissionandroid:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" />
```

Comment: Also, remember to add permission `android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES` if target API > 25. Otherwise nothing will happen.

Answer (score 3):

If the File Provider is not being found in the manifest file you have to do something like this to define it:

```
<provider
    android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="com.mydomain.fileprovider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    ...
</provider>
```

Here is a link to the documentation on setting up FileProviders.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html

Comment: well, I do not have any class named `fileprovider` does it make any issue? and what is `com.mydomain`? and what should be instead of `...` thanks.

Comment: the authority is just the package name you have your package set to: com.myapp.myapp. Which means that is what you would replace as the authority.

Comment: And the name doesn't have to be called fileprovider, it could be called anything

Comment: I would read the link that I have in my answer, it tells you all about the FileProvider

Comment: @sajadabasi Could you accept my answer if it has helped you?

Comment: I want to access a folder in `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` what file provider should I use? I tried some but it says the package can not found. @Aaron