# Installation dialog not shown in oreo when done programatically if device is not rooted

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo, android-update-app

I am trying to update app after showing the alert dialog in my app. It is working fine below Android Oreo. Here is what I have tried till now

```
String ANDROID_PACKAGE = "application/vnd.android.package-archive";
                    File update_apk = new File(context.getFilesDir(), intent.getStringExtra("update_file"));
                    Intent notificationIntent;
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                        notificationIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE);
                        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                        notificationIntent.setDataAndType(
                                FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".fileprovider", update_apk),
                                ANDROID_PACKAGE);
                    } else {
                        notificationIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                        notificationIntent.setDataAndType(
                                Uri.parse("file://" + update_apk.getAbsolutePath()),
                                ANDROID_PACKAGE);
                    }
                    startActivity(notificationIntent);
```

How to show this app update dialog in the devices which are not rooted. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in aadvance.

Comment: use [this library](https://github.com/Blankj/AndroidUtilCode). which provide the code for checking device rooted or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Check below permission in your manifest.xml file.**

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" />`

Also check your file provider for Intent.VIEW_ACTION.

More reference check this page [Android install apk with Intent.VIEW_ACTION not working with File provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39147608/android-install-apk-with-intent-view-action-not-working-with-file-provider/40131196#40131196)

enjoy code.