# Android APK Intent goes to wrong link

Tags: android

I would like to implement an on click event which prompts the user to download an APK to update my app to the latest version:

```
public void f(View view) {
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://www.example.com/app-release.apk");
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri));
}
```

I build the app and deploy it to my phone.  I start the app and click on the button.  The browser opens.  In the address bar I see very briefly the URL of the APK.  Then this URL disappears and the browser goes to whatever page I visited most recently before the test.  The APK is not downloaded.

I have ensured that the version number of the APK to be installed exceeds the version number of the app in which I test the button click.  The URL of the APK is valid, and if I explicitly visit that URL in the browser, the APK installs.  I enabled android.permission.INTERNET in the manifest.  On the phone I have allowed installation of apps from unknown sources, and in Play Store I turned off scanning of non playstore apps.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

**Edit #1**:  I am not trying to implement code within my app to download the APK to local storage.  I'm simply trying to launch a browser window pointed at the URL of the APK.  I'm attempting something similar to the approach described here:

https://juristr.com/blog/2011/02/coding-update-functionality-for-your/

In that solution, the code to prompt for the download of the APK is:

```
Intent updateIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
       Uri.parse("http://some-public-url/deploy/MyApplication.apk"));
startActivity(updateIntent);
```

That's what I want to do.  But it doesn't begin the download.  The URL flashes briefly in the address bar, but then the browser goes back to whatever page it was on before.

**Edit #2**: If I kick it off using the debugger and the virtual device, the code behaves as I expect. If I install the APK to my physical device, and click on the button there, it malfunctions as I described above. Both the physical device and the virtual one are the Nexus 5.

I have created two versions of the APK, a "version 1" and a "version 2".  From within version 1 I would like to trigger a download and install of version 2.

Comment: If you want to download something directly, you should me looking into Android's Download Manager API. It's pretty simple, and will be more reliable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit :**
Collected all information so that we can have a check list

- Check that application has Permission to WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
- Check that application as permission REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES
- Check that the device has enough space in the device
- If your URL is http, does the browser support http?
- The APK that you want to install must have the same name as the APK which installed the instance that launches the request.
- any suspicious info on the Logcat?

**Previous :**
Did you get permission to Write External?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39147608/android-install-apk-with-intent-view-action-not-working-with-file-provider) is similar to your problem

Comment: thanks for getting back to me.  it seems unlikely to me that WriteExternal is relevant, it relates to downloading a file to local storage, i'm simply attempting to launch a browser window pointed to the URL of the APK.

that page you linked mentions the permission REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES and i tried adding that but it didn't help.

Comment: did 3rd part installation is turned on on phone settings?

Comment: On the phone I have allowed installation of apps from unknown sources, and in Play Store I turned off scanning of non playstore apps.

Comment: enough space on the device?

Comment: i think there must be, because if i go in to the browser and visit the URL of the APK, it prompts me to download it, then installs it successfully.  i just want to trigger that behavior from within my app.

Comment: Anything unusual log cat?

Comment: i just kicked it off using the debugger and the virtual device, so that i could see the log file - and in that environment the code behaves as i expect.  if i install the APK to my physical device, and click on the button there, it fails as i described in the OP.  both the physical device and the virtual one are the nexus 5.

Comment: Your URL is http not https maybe the browser refuse this from intents?

Comment: What phone you have? What are the android versions?

Comment: i have not given you the real URL that i am using.  in fact it is https.  i tried experimenting with http, www, etc., no joy.  i'm on the nexus 5.

Comment: awesome.  many thanks for your edit.  i accepted your answer.  may i suggest that you edit "The APK that you want to install must have the same name as the APK..." and append: "... which installed the instance that launches the request."

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out.  The APK that you want to install must have the same name as the APK which spawned the instance that is attempting the download.  I tried to introduce a version number into the name of the APK, that's what broke it.  Many thanks for all of the kind assistance!

edit: see @kelalaka's answer, which is more complete.