# Build, Install APK using Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, apk

When I try to install an APK using:

```
val installIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE); 
    installIntent.setData(Uri.fromFile(true_path));
    startActivity(installIntent);
```

I receive the error:

```
file:///...app-debug.apk exposed beyond app through Intent.getData()
```

I believe that intents cannot use file:// URIs; how do I build an APK using Android Studio, such that it can be used by an intent?

Comment: It's nothing to do with how you build the apk. It's just that you can no longer send file URIs on `Intent`s. There's an answer with a rather complete example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40131196.

Answer (score -1):

The correct way to do it is

```
File file = new File(dir, "App.apk");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), 
"application/vnd.android.package-archive");
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: All you've done is make a new file called APK, then used the setDataAndType instead of setData. I am asking how to build the APK such that it is usable by an intent.